# Javascript error while requiring bignumber.js : Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-management

I am trying to require bignumber.js in my Javascript file:

```
var BigNumber = require('bignumber.js');
```

but I am getting the following:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Any Solutions?

Comment: Did you imported it? See https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/

Comment: yes I do ! @Phanti

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Client on node: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)